# Accessing SQL Table from Another Computer

Tags: sql, database, html, network-programming

The best way I think to explain this is to tell you what my overall goal is. I am trying to develop a web app to read and write to and from a table located on a central computer. The changes made from one device should be visible when the table is read from other devices.

What I have right now:

- Right now I do not have a central table like I am wanting. Because what I think is happening is each device is creating it's own SQL table to edit.
- Each device connects to a networked computer to display the web page/ UI (where it edits it's own tables)
- If it means anything, I am using JavaScript

If anyone could help me out that would be great or if someone could point me in the right direction would be just as appreciated!

I am completely lost right as to how to do this.

Comment: Surely your web app will be hosted on a server, and that server can have a single SQL server?

Comment: What kind of database server hosts the database in which this table resides? Postgres? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc? Are these mobile devices that are writing to the tables? How are they creating their own tables? Where are they creating these tables?

Comment: SQL Databases are not accessible directly from Javascript or other client-based code. You'll need to use a server-side language to talk to the SQL database. It would be helpful if you had a listing of the technologies in use here (web server platform, backend web platform, etc).

Comment: @swasheck I am going to use MySQL (Is that what I have to do is set up a server?), Yes they are and I am assuming that is what is happening if they all have diffident data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have to connect to the same `SQL` server to have access to the same database.

Let's say you are programming with C#.Net and you want to connect to that database which is hosted on an other computer. You will have a connection string :

`SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=SERVER_NAME;Database=DATABASE_NAME;User id=Your_Id; Password=Your_Password");`

where SERVER_NAME is the name of the server you are hosting elsewhere and DATABASE_Name the name of your database you want to work with.

Host a single server.

You should develop a structure for your'e database. All the tables, views and stored procedures(routines in mysql). This way the devices will just read/write information in the tables.

I don't quite understand in which context the devices are allowed to create tables. If it isn't necessary don't let them do this. If your table is already created on your server and devices try to read/write in it then there is no way that a device will create it's own copy.

Comment: No problem don't hesitate if you have any questions.